# DNS - Remove Active Directory Integrated Forwarder on One Server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns, windows-dns

The zone in question is currently held on a single Windows 2003 Domain Controller in a remote office (the result of an acquisition), and I would like to create secondary zones at other locations in order to provide a level of resilience to DNS resolution through various company offices.

The problem is that when I try and remove the conditional forwarders for this domain on the DNS servers that I would like to add the secondary zones to, I receive the following warning:

*Warning: This is an Active Directory-integrated forwarder. If you decide to delete this forwarder from the DNS server, it will also be deleted from Active Directory. The forwarder also will be deleted from all DNS servers that load this forwarder from Active Directory.*

To clarify - if forwarders on other Domain Controllers for this specific domain are deleted, that is acceptable, as each one will have the DNS server with the new secondary zone listed as a forwarder.

What worries me is the line 'it will also be deleted from Active Directory'. I suppose I'm just looking for clarification that the zone will still exist on the 2003 box and that there will be no adverse effects (assuming that all other DNS servers have, or have access to, the newly configured secondary zones).

Comment: Why are you using primary and secondary zones rather than AD integrated zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual zone will exist on the other servers.

The line about being deleted from AD is in relation to it being deleted from the NTDS.dit file.  Once it's removed from the .dit file then there will be no LDAP queries against it either.

To be sure though, you will still have your dns forward lookup zone.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I've removed the AD integrated forwarder and added the secondary zone to other locations, ensuring first that they are listed as name servers for the zone. As you said, there were no issues with the forward lookup zone on the original server.